# DateTimeControl ondatechanged event not firing

Tags: sharepoint

I have a DateTimeControl with an ondatechanged event. When I change the day, the event is fired, but when I change the hour in the dropdown, the event is not fired, how can I do it ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following lines of code on the `Page_Load` event

```
foreach (Control c in dtControl.Controls)
{
  if (c is DropDownList) 
  { 
    ((DropDownList)c).AutoPostBack = true; 
    ((DropDownList)c).SelectedIndexChanged += SomeEvent; 
  }
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol_events.aspx